# Writing app logic in custom model strongloop

Tags: strongloop

Hi i am new to strongloop i want to know can i write my app logic inside a custom model. Like in example below i am getting data from orders table and on success i want to use its response in my logic.

```
Orders.createOrder = function(cb) {
Orders.findById( userId, function (err, instance) {
    response = "Name of coffee shop is " + instance.name;
    cb(null, response);

/***** want to write my logic here *****/


    console.log(response);
});
cb(null, response);
};
Orders.remoteMethod(
'createOrder',
{
  http: {path: '/createOrder', verb: 'get'},
  returns: {arg: 'status', type: 'string'}
}
);
```

so is it the write place to do it or i have to write it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several issues, but the answer is pretty much yes.

You should call the callback function `cb` when your application logic is done, and not before. Also, you should pay attention to feed any errors to the `cb`, otherwise you're in for some big debugging headaches down the road.

Also, you need to pay extra attention to the way you're calling callbacks. In your current code, `cb` will be called twice for any request, at the very end of `createOrder` and in `findById`. This is not good, because for one request you tell the server you have completed two. Also, the callback at the end of `createOrder` is called immediately, before `findById` is complete.

So corrected code would look like this

```js
Orders.createOrder = function(cb) {
  Orders.findById( userId, function (err, instance) {
    // Don't forget stop execution and feed errors to callback if needed
    // (other option : if errors are part of normal flow, process them and continue of course)
    if (err) return cb(err);
    
    response = "Name of coffee shop is " + instance.name;
    console.log(response);
    
    // Application logic goes there
    
    // Complete the remote method
    cb(null, response);
  });
  // No calls here to the callback
};
Orders.remoteMethod(
'createOrder',
{
  http: {path: '/createOrder', verb: 'get'},
  returns: {arg: 'status', type: 'string'}
}
);
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply... :)

Comment: If my code helped, please accept my answer or click the up-arrow to indicate it was relevant. Thank you.